# Connect-VIServer not working with passed credentials, but works with integrated authentication

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I ran into a problem today, with a script which used to work correctly. It connects to a vCenter server via PowerCLI, and does some stuff. The problem is that I can no longer connect to the server via script, when I specify the credentials. Neither of the following two commands work:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -Credential $cred
```

or

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName -User $userName -Password $password
```

Both return the message "Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password".

So naturally, I double and triple checked that I didn't have a typo when specifying either of them. I've tried this from multiple systems, using different users, so I suspect that the problem is on the server.

Interestingly, if I start PowerShell as a Windows domain user with permissions for the server, and don't specify anything for credentials, it works fine:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server $serverName
```

Has anyone ever run into this, and hopefully have a solution as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Are you able to log into the vSphere client using the credentials you are trying to use in the script?

Comment: Do you know if changes were made to your vCenter environment around the time when the script stopped working? Or after the last time it worked correctly?

Comment: I hadn't thought of trying that. It turns out that I can log in when checking the box to use the current Windows credentials, but not if I specify the username / password. Apparently, this is not a PowerCLI issue, but a server authentication issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be an issue with server authentication, not a PowerCLI issue. The same issue is seen when logging into both the desktop and web clients. These KB articles seem relevant, and I've forwarded them to the sysadmin for the server:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2043070

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034798

It turned out to be be a problem with the SSO service.

Answer (score -2):

Instead use below:

```
$cred = get-credential
Connect-VIServer -Server ServerName -cred $cred
```